# Can matter be mass and energy simultaneously?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass

I am well aware of the fact that this question is very elementary and I should not have posted it on StackExchange. I wouldn't have had, but most of the reddit forums where I ask questions have gone dark. So please take it a bit kindly.

I have often heard that Einstein's Theory of Special Relativity claims mass and energy to be the same thing. Does it mean that if there is a mass, I may consider it to be energy and vice versa? I think not. I think that something can exist as only one of the two at one instant but can be interconverted.
This doubt came into my mind when a famous person (I won't disclose his name) claimed that most of our bodies' mass comes not from the mass of atoms but rather from their energies. Now, I wouldn't have believed it if the person was just anybody but this person is actually really famous in science education, so I came here to confirm.

Comment: Maybe reading this, paragraphs  on mass and energy will help you   https://schoolbag.info/chemistry/dummies/2.html

Comment: *I have often heard that Einstein's Theory of Special Relativity rules mass and energy to be the same thing.* This is a misconception. It doesn’t say that they are the same thing. It actually says that $E^2=(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2$.

Comment: I've hidden a comment that should have been posted as an answer, and some replies to it. To post a brief answer, please post a brief answer. Use comments to clarify or improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

The right question would be:

*can matter have mass and energy simultaneously?*

The answer is Yes.

In spite of the so-called mass-energy equivalence, they are two distinct *properties* of matter. Energy depends on the reference frame and (rest) mass does not. Energy is conserved and (rest) mass is not. However part of the energy arises from mass according to the famous formula $E=mc^2$.

Comment: @hft thanks for editing, I did not spot that macroscopic  typo!

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 2):

> I have often heard that Einstein's Theory of Special Relativity rules mass and energy to be the same thing. Does it mean that of there is a mass, can I consider it to be energy or vice versa?

This causes a lot of confusion because the terminology changed over time. In the early days, when relativity was first being introduced to the public, we used the word "mass" to mean the ratio of force to acceleration (based on Newton's 2nd law $F=ma$, so $m=F/a)$, which increases as you get faster (because as you get closer to the speed of light, your measured acceleration reduces to keep you under the speed limit), and we used the term "rest mass" to mean the minimum, non-removable mass of a particle at rest.

Using this old definition of "mass", it turns out that mass and energy are different names for the same thing. To try to reduce the confusion, it was sometimes called "relativistic mass". As something gets faster, its kinetic energy increases, so its mass increases, which means that it gets ever more resistant to being pushed to go faster. As you approach the speed of light, its relativistic mass approaches infinity. This old definition is the source of what you heard.

After a while, physicists realised it was silly to have two names for the same physical quantity, so they changed the definitions. Now "rest mass" was to be called just "mass", and "energy" was just energy. We don't have to apply adjectives, and we have two different words for two different concepts. Now the mass (rest mass) doesn't change as an object's speed increases, but its energy does. So mass is no longer the same thing as energy.

But it also means that mass is no longer conserved. The masses of particles going into a collision doesn't have to equal the masses of the particle's coming out of it. So it does require a bit of a change in thinking.

> This doubt came into my mind where a famous person (I won't disclose his name) claimed that most of our bodies' mass comes from not the mass of atoms but from their energies.

OK, this is a bit deeper. It turns out that the two concepts of "relativistic mass" and "rest mass" are not as well-separated as we initially thought. If we have several particles that are bound together, so we can think of them as if they are bouncing around at extremely high speed inside a box, we can think of it as individual particles with small rest masses but a huge relativistic mass, or we can think of it as a single stationary "box" particle with a huge rest mass.

The quarks in a proton or neutron have a tiny rest mass, but because they are 'bouncing around' at high speed in the nucleus (I'm grossly simplifying the quantum mechanical details here), they have a very big relativistic mass. When we look at a proton as a whole, the quarks' relativistic mass (the energy, in modern terminology) gets reclassified as the proton's rest mass (the mass). Thus, in the modern vocabulary, the mass (of the proton/neutron) is largely coming from the energy (of the quarks).

Comment: Very nice answer. Some nitpicks: relativistic mass is defined by the relation $\mathbf p = m \mathbf v$, rather than by Newton's 2nd law. And in proton, as in any composed charged body, part of the positive contribution to rest mass should be also due to EM repulsion of two of the quarks (electromagnetic mass).

Answer (score 0):

Energy is really more fundamental than mass. The modern conception of mass is that it is the minimum amount of energy a system can possess ("rest mass"). And indeed what you've heard is true: most of the rest mass of everyday objects comes from the relative motion of subatomic particles and from the binding energy holding them together. Only a tiny fraction is due to the particles' rest masses.

Einstein's famous equation was originally written in the form $m = \frac{E}{c^2}$ as showing how much inertia the energy content of a body has. In some sense most mass (inertia) arises in this way.

Comment: I would suggest adding to this that if one has had only high school physics, one has only encountered gravitational and inertial mass, both of which are strictly $E/c^2$ where E is the total mass-energy, and not (quite) the $m$ in $E^2 = m^2c^4+p^2c^2$, which IMO people are much too eager to whip out and show beginners before teaching them the modern-physics definition of mass and how it differs from inertia.

Comment: (although $c^4$ being 90 thousand trillion times bigger than $c^2$, the difference is usually negligible)

Comment: @gs At LHC it isn't and neither is it negligible in precision spectroscopy where relativistic effects are quite strong once we go past hydrogen and towards heavier nuclei. The universe plays a bad joke on us by making us live in a tiny corner of energy-momentum space that totally doesn't matter for the fundamentals. At least that's my take on it.

Comment: @gs only because of our chosen system of units!  That is another bit of old-fashioned SR "sleight of hand" ;)